# Debugging SMTP Mail

Tags: php, email

I've got a box that is running a very old version of PHP & xpertmailer.
It works fine for most email addresses, but seems to fail on one domain. (there may be more but I've only been alerted to one)

I'm trying to work out how to enable DEBUG and see what the issue is.
apache logs shows the errors are in SMTP.php on line 240 & 426:

240

```
if (!fwrite($conn, 'QUIT'.$_smtp->CRLF)) $_RESULT[300] = 'can not write';
```

426

```
if (!fwrite($conn, $line.$_smtp->CRLF)) {
                        $_RESULT[328] = 'can not write';
                        $continue = false;
                        break;
                    }
```

The mailer commands are:

```
$e = explode('@', $t);
$conn = SMTP::mxconnect($e[1]) or die(print_r($_RESULT));
$sent = SMTP::send($conn, array($t), $b, $f);
```

Any one know how to do this ? 
Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($e); die;`. Just check each variable with their info within it, and see if all data are correct. (to start with).

Comment: thanks but `$e` is just the email address exploded on the @ symbol.

Comment: Hi tom, what i mean is you should debug from the first variable untill the last one. Do this untill you've found an error. Most of the times while debugging i encounter typos or wrong data being given.